# Cronjobs not showing up using crontab -u <user> -l

Tags: cron

I added some jobs directly to the

```
/etc/crontab
```

file. They are running fine. However, I cannot see them if I use the ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`crontab‍‍` command

```
crontab -u <user> -l
```

Do I have to reindex the file somehow or could this be caused by bad formatting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User crontabs are stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`. You can't use the `crontab` command to see or edit the system crontab `/etc/crontab`.

Note that only the system crontab contains a user field after the date. User crotab entries  are always run the corresponding user so they don't need an user field.

Answer (score 3):

No, you are using TWO different systems.

```
crontab -u <user> -l
```

will list all jobs added with `crontab -e`.

```
/etc/crontab
```

is not part of `crontab` but from another procedure.

Both are there for historical compatibility. And the big difference is permissions. User cron jobs will run with the permissions of that user, system cron jobs run with the permissions of root. `/etc/crontab` tried to solve that by adding a "user" to the colunms.

I would advice to pick one and stick with it. It can get messy rather quickly. My favourite is `/etc/crontab` unless you need to hide something then I would use  crontab from "root".

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. When you add lines on the `/etc/crontab` it's not really attribuate to a profile  but the system.

If you want to add a  crontab to an user:

```
crontab -e -u  <user>
```

The users' crontab are stored on the folder  `/var/spool/cron` if  you  want to see the files.